# Search file for matching IP address in Linux

Tags: linux, file, search, awk, ip-address

I have file with allocated IP address ranges. It looks something like this:

```
...
arin|US|ipv4|8.0.0.0|16777216|19921201|allocated
arin|US|ipv4|9.0.0.0|16777216|19881216|assigned
apnic|ID|ipv4|122.200.144.0|2048|20061023|allocated
apnic|TW|ipv4|122.200.152.0|2048|20080424|allocated
apnic|AU|ipv4|122.200.160.0|4096|20061020|allocated
apnic|AU|ipv4|122.200.176.0|4096|20110121|allocated
apnic|JP|ipv4|122.200.192.0|8192|20061023|allocated
...
```

My question is if it is possible and how to get specific row from this file using an IP address as search parameter in Linux by using tools like grep, awk or some other tools.

e.g. if the searched IP is 8.8.8.8 the result should be:

```
arin|US|ipv4|8.0.0.0|16777216|19921201|allocated
```

EDIT// FUll ipv4 list can be found here http://skechboy.com/ips/ipv4_table

Comment: What are those fields?  Is the 5th column the size of the network?

Comment: @dward-thomson Yep that is the number of assigned ips in the specific network. This data is publicly available by the Regional Internet Registries [link](https://www.arin.net/knowledge/rirs.html)

Comment: why 8.8.8.8 whould match a line `8.0.0.0` ? could you explain?

Comment: 8.8.8.8 should match 8.0.0.0 because it is allocated to this network,  0 is defining range from 0 to 255 so all between 8.1.1.1 and / 8.255.255.255 are assigned to 8.0.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if 4th and 5th columns are [network prefix and subnet mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnetting) then to grep input for an ip:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput, socket, struct, sys

# x.x.x.x string -> integer
ip2int = lambda ipstr: struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton(ipstr))[0]    

ip = ip2int(sys.argv.pop(1)) # get ip from command-line
for line in fileinput.input(): # read from stdin or file(s) given at command-line
    try:
        family, network_prefix, subnet_mask = line.split('|')[2:5]
        if (family == 'ipv4' and
            (ip & (2**32 - int(subnet_mask))) == ip2int(network_prefix)):
            print line,
    except Exception:
        print >>sys.stderr, "can't parse", line,
```

#### Example

```
$ python grep-ip.py 192.168.5.193 <<'.'
x|x|ipv4|192.168.5.128|64|x|x
x|x|ipv4|192.168.5.192|64|x|x
x|x|ipv4|192.168.5.0|64|x|x
x|x|ipv4|192.168.5.0|256|x|x
.
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/TyqV6)

```
x|x|ipv4|192.168.5.192|64|x|x
x|x|ipv4|192.168.5.0|256|x|x
```

Comment: Look's great but I'm having trouble to test on large file to be more specific this one `http://skechboy.com/ips/ipv4_table`. I suck in python and I know this is very noob-ish question but how can I set the input data to be from file?

Comment: @SkechBoy: if you put the script into `grep-ip` file and `chmod +x` it then the usage is: `./grep-ip ip [FILE...]` like grep: search the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name).

Comment: @SkechBoy: there are several lines in `ipv4_table` that are not in a given format. I've changed the script to ignore them.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the awk implementation of @ugoren method:

```
sphynx@fjord% cat ipgrep.awk

BEGIN { FS = "|"; }

{
    ip = ip2num(ADDR);
    network_start = ip2num($4);
    network_length = $5;
    if (ip >= network_start && ip <= network_start + network_length) {
        print;
    }
}

function ip2num(ip)
{
    split(ip, addr, ".");
    return addr[1] * 2^24 + addr[2] * 2^16 + addr[3] * 2^8 + addr[4];
}


sphynx@fjord% awk -v ADDR=8.8.8.8 -f ipgrep.awk data 
arin|US|ipv4|8.0.0.0|16777216|19921201|allocated
```

Comment: it matches more than it should. [gawk](http://ideone.com/OSbWy), [mawk](http://ideone.com/UA24y).

Comment: +1: it [works](http://ideone.com/0ewc6). But it is slower than the [Python version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9351292/4279) (that is strange).

Comment: You should exclude the right boundary `ip < (network_start + network_length)`. `9.0.0.0` should not match `8.0.0.0|16777216`. Compare [`awk`](http://ideone.com/Lg7Fm) and [#5 for python](http://ideone.com/TyqV6)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can be used, this way:
1. Run with the `-F'|'` parameter, to separate by the vertical bar. Now `$4` is the first address, `$5` is the network size.
2. Use `split($4,addr,'.')` To get an array `a` with the 4 address parts
3. Do some math to get the numeric address: `range_start=a[0]*16777216+a[1]*65536+a[2]*256+a[3]`.
4. Do the same math on the address you're looking for.
5. Now just check if the address is in the range, between `range_start` and `range_start+$5`

Comment: I'm trying this method combined with the one suggested by @shiplu I think that it's going to be much faster in it's execution.