# how do i do a range regex in ruby like awk /start/,/stop/

Tags: python, ruby, regex, awk

I want to do an AWK-style range regex like this:

```
awk ' /hoststatus/,/\}/' file
```

In AWK this would print all the lines between the two patterns in a file:

```
hoststatus {
host_name=myhost
modified_attributes=0
check_command=check-host-alive
check_period=24x7
notification_period=workhours
check_interval=5.000000
retry_interval=1.000000
event_handler=
}
```

How do I do that in Ruby?

Bonus: How would you do it in Python?

This is really powerful in AWK, but I'm new to Ruby, and not sure how you'd do it.  In Python I was also unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby:

```
str =
"drdxrdx
hoststatus {
host_name=myhost
modified_attributes=0
check_command=check-host-alive
check_period=24x7
notification_period=workhours
check_interval=5.000000
retry_interval=1.000000
event_handler=
}"
str.each_line do |line|
  print line if line =~ /hoststatus/..line =~ /\}/
end
```

This is the infamous [flip-flop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111286/when-would-a-ruby-flip-flop-be-useful).

Comment: @Tim Schaefer It is not a regex, it is two regexes switching each other on as the active one. AFAIK Ruby stole this from Perl, Perl stole it from AWK.

Answer (score 1):

with python passing in the multiline and dotall flags to re. The ? following the * makes it non-greedy

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('test.x') as f:
...     print re.findall('^hoststatus.*?\n\}$', f.read(), re.DOTALL + re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Basically the same as mine, (but maybe a little better).  Still, this has the disadvantage that you end up reading the entire file at once as opposed to reading line-by-line as I assume `awk` does.  (I bet `awk` would do this faster too :)

Comment: @mgilson, agreed. The only tool that I am aware of that can do multiline matches with full regex power and not just the ability to specify ranges, and without loading entire file into memory is pcregrep.

Comment: I was not able to make this work.  I've been trying lots of variations on this one and still can't get it to work in python.  Thanks anyway... Tim

Comment: @mgilson: performance depends on many things e.g., [python greps for an ip in a file faster than awk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9350264/4279) (both version are not written for speed). It is not clear what is faster (for some input) re.findall() or awk's flip-flop