# How to Select Specific value in Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

```
COD(CdTypCd_'SPC_fghfh')
COD(CdTypCd_'SPC.,/'][[]\=-09&^%$#@!~*/-*-*/-/-/-*/-*+@#$$%áèÿó')
COD(CdTypCd_'SPC')
COD(CdTypCd_'SPC@#$$áèÿó%')
```

I need to select  `' '` inside the single quotes values using regular expression

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nY4fA7/1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i do a range regex in ruby like awk /start/,/stop/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980500/how-do-i-do-a-range-regex-in-ruby-like-awk-start-stop)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have quotes inside single quoted string(2nd line), you will have to use greedy matching:

```
(?<=').*(?=')
```

to get text between single quotes (https://regex101.com/r/nF0bM7/2)

To get text exactly between single quotes use non greedy matching like this:  https://regex101.com/r/jA6hB6/1